# can not delegate the detail view controller to the master view controller

Tags: swift

Hello I tried using delegate to connect my Master and Detail view controllers.

In the master view controller I got this above the class:

```
protocol CategorySelectionDelegate: class {
    func categorySelected(id: Int)
    func progress(percentage: Float)
}
```

and within the class I declare it as:

```
weak var delegate: CategorySelectionDelegate?
```

In the detail view controller I do

```
extension DetailViewController: CategorySelectionDelegate {
    func categorySelected(id: Int) {

        print("set row \(id)")

        selectedCategoryID = id
    }

    func progress(percentage: Float) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.progressView.setProgress(percentage, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```

So far so good. Everything works. But when I try to connect them both by doing

```
self.delegate = DetailViewController
```

Inside the viewDidLoad in my MasterViewController it says "cannot assign value of type 'DetailViewController.Type' to 'CategorySelectionDelegate?'"

What am I Doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are assigning delegate in wrong class if you have created delegate in master view controller class then you want to respond to delegate in detail view controller then you need to assign like this in Detail view controller...

Let masterVC : MasterlViewController = MasterViewController()
masterVC.delegate = self

Now in above line you will get same error as you told above so you must include delegate name in class as we do for uitableview datasource ...

Class DetailViewController :UIViewController ,CategorySelectionDelegate

Comment: That way he will take a random MasterVC and not the one loaded.. It still doesn't work.